# How to "do, if expression increased"?

Tags: c++, multithreading, if-statement, vector, bitcoin

I have the Bitcoin source code (**multithreaded**) and I'm intending to add some new lines. On Bitcoin network data messages are exchanged where data are stored in vectors. I want to implement some *instrunction* whenever a vector increases in size:

How can I code following pattern in C++ in order to execute statements inside if:

```
if ("vVector.size() did not increase")
//*instruction*
```

?

NOTE: vVector is incremented automatically from time to time. It's actually a clone of another vector that collects things and expands without me having and willing to have control on it.

### EDIT:

When I do:

```
if (!(vVector.size()++))
//do whatever is here
```

I get following error:
***lvalue required as increment operand***

vVector is filled inside another function of the same cpp-file by a function that is declared in a separate header file.

here's a code snippet with a short description: http://hastebin.com/amisuvafab.coffee

Comment: Your code and question are ridiculous.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Do you have a better idea how I can solve my problem in a short time?

Comment: You haven't said what your problem is. All you've done is post some code that can't possibly compile let alone do anything practical.

Comment: @JonathanPotter how can I put this in terms of C++ syntax: if (_"vector size increased"_) {//do something} ?

Comment: You have two answers below that answer that specific question quite well. But as they have pointed out and you seem to have ignored, vector size simply can't increase using `vector.size()++`.

Comment: I had edited my question after I got the answers.

Comment: And it still makes no sense.

Comment: basically, where to compare to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as this

```
int prevSize = vVector.size();
// do something here

if (vVector.size() == prevSize) {
    // do whatever is here.
}
```

**EDIT**

```
if (!(vVector.size()++))
```

This statement is plain wrong. `size()` method returns the value (const) of the size of vector, not the reference. So you cannot increment it. `AddInventoryHonest()` adds to the vector using `push_back()`. So the return value of `size()` method will change with every call to `push_back`. Hence this will work in this scenario.

**EDIT 2**:
To handle the multithreaded case, use condition variable (just an example)

```
int prevSize = vVector.size();
// do something

std::mutex mtx;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
std::condition_variable cv;

bool size_did_not_increase() {
    return vVector.size() == prevSize;
}

cv.wait(lck, size_did_not_increase());
```

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately your answer doesn't work because as vVector.size() is adapted from time to time the if-expression will always be true, right?

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi can you show a code snippet where this doesn't work ?

Comment: this is a short snippet where it doesn't work: http://hastebin.com/amisuvafab.coffee

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi I assume your code isn't multithreaded, so if you don't insert anything to the vector before the if-conditional (at the comment do something), how will the size change ?

Comment: Actually my code is multithreaded. It's the bitcoin source code. I'll edit my question with a note to multithreading.

Answer (score 4):

```
int init_size = v.size();
...
if(init_size == v.size()) {
  // do whatever is here
}
```

On Edit:

A `std::vector`'s size is increased only if you insert an element to it. Thus, `vVector.size()++` makes no sense in the first place.

The reason you're getting the error is because, doing `if(!(vVector.size()++))` is illegal. `std::vector::size` member function will return an `rvalue` instead of an `lvalue` that the post-increment `operator++` requires. Now on the difference between an `rvalue` and `lvalue` see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues).

Comment: it should be `v.size()`

Comment: @101010: Thanks. Is there an alternative to your answer?

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi if you want to check whether your vector contains any elements just `if(!Vvector.empty())`

Comment: @101010 ok, I knew this one but with the hint of Shreevardhan I edited my question with a note about the code being multithreaded.